# What does the push pin icon adornment mean in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Whenever I exclude a .h file from the build and then re-include it later, the icon for the .h file in the Project Explorer will have a push-pin adornment. I looked on the CDT User Guide but it's not on their [list of icons](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_cproj_view.htm). What does the push pin mean?

Comment: To fix the wrench icon, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28202016/2508150)

Answer (score 2):

You may have uncovered a small bug in CDT!

You did not include an image in your original question so I'm going to propose that the icon overlay you are seeing is not a push-pin, but an indicator that the properties for this element (the include file) have been modified (it looks like a little wrench).  When you exclude the element it gets an overlay indicating exclusion, when you re-include the element you see the wrench overlay.  This is the bug since you have returned the element to its unmodified state.  The wrench overlay should not be displayed in this case.

If you try excluding C source file you'll see the exclusion overlay, and when you re-include the C source file the exclusion overlay is removed and only the original icon (with no overlay) is displayed.

(I tried this using CDT 7.0.0)

Comment: I don't know about C files, but C++ files also display the wrench. And worse, the IDE refuses to build the project, complaining about some NPE

Answer (score 0):

I had different versions of a cpp file that I wanted to try. By interchanging them, the newly included file had such a small wrench in the icon. It appears to be a small bug.

Solution:

create new file, copy contents, delete old file, rename new file to the name of the old file, done.

Answer (score 0):

### Wrench Icon ⟹ custom settings

This icon was introduced a long time ago in 2009 — [see Bug #298540](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=298540)

It shows up whenever the local settings for some resource override the inherited global or project defaults. Unfortunately, this does not reveal the actual reason, as any object in the tree can have a lot of settings — the **Properties** dialog (right click > "Properties") is complex and has several tabs.

- you may have added a local `#define` symbol "C++ General > Paths and Symbols"
- you may have added a specific include or include directory
- if you're using a *»non managed build«* (i.e. you are calling an external makefile), and you're using "discovery", than it might happen that the **CDB Build Output Parser** captured a compiler invocation for that resource and inferred an include or other setting beyond the general defaults.
- just selecting a custom encoding or adding a specific language mapping *does not* seem to cause that display

If you click the "Restore Defaults" button on all relevant tabs of the Properties dialog of that resource, the wrench icon disappears.