# What is the meaning of this decorated folder icon in Eclipse/CDT project explorer?

Tags: eclipse, icons, cvs, eclipse-cdt

What does this special folder icon in CDT/Eclipse project explorer mean? The bluish thingy looks like a key or screw or some kind of tool. I guess it has something to do with CVS. I couldn't find the info in the Preferences > Appearance > Label Decorations settings.

[image: A zoomed screen capture]

Comment: It looks more of like a wrench.

This could be of help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209388/what-does-the-push-pin-icon-adornment-mean-in-eclipse-cdt

Comment: Indeed, it could be a wrench - with a quite short handle, though :)  Only one folder in my project has it, and I have absolutely no idea why.

Answer (score 15):

The wrench icon over a folder or file means that it is overriding some of the build settings inherited from its parent.  If it's there by accident, you most likely right-clicked that folder instead of the entire project and changed some of its properties.

To fix it, right click the folder with the wrench icon, go to its properties, and click "restore defaults" on each of the categories that differ from the main project.

Comment: How does one know which categories have different settings?

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be [custom resource setting](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=298540), also shown in the [CDT 7.0 release news](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn70) (do a page search for overlay).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but it is unclear if the icon appears due to a bug or it really means something useful at this stage... I have Helios Eclipse with CDT Version 7.0.2.201102110609.

Comment: It has a meaning, albeit a somewhat obscure one. See my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78141255/444796

Answer (score 2):

When you have a include path pointed into a directory, then that directory will have a key symbol